# Call ps1 from cmd

Tags: powershell

I want to call ps1 from command line, there are 2 files in same folder (very straight forward)

`test.cmd`:

```
@set powershell=powershell.exe
echo ^^^&'%~dpn0.ps1' %*| "%powershell%" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command -
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

`test.ps1`:

```
ls>abc.txt
```

The problem is:
When I call test.cmd from command line, abc.txt does't get generated. but When I call test.ps1 from powershell ise from that folder, abc.txt is created. I'm also be able to call powershell.exe from that folder as well.

Did I miss something?

> This issue was sorted. I have 's in my folder's name, once I remove it, it's working fine.
>
> Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `ls>test.txt` worked by just running the `test.ps1` script?

You have to write is as `ls > test.txt` for it to work and I have confirmed that that works from `test.cmd` as well.

Comment: Thank Manojlds, this issue was sorted out, pls see my comments.